# visual state manager in XAML for UWP is not working

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am new to UWP development and working on XAML. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following XAML where visual state is not working. when I resize the window, the values of rows and columns do not change. Also the background color of the stack panel does not change.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="40,0,0,0">

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Ticket}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ticket">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel00.Background" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel00.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel00.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel01.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel01.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel10.(Grid.Row)" Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel10.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel11.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel11.(Grid.Row)" Value="3" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="WideLayout">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1100" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel00.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel00.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel01.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel01.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel10.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel10.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel11.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Target="StackPanel11.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel00" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel Name="StackPanel000" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketLineLabel" Text="Ticket Line: " />
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketLineData" Text="{x:Bind Line}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Name="StackPanel001" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketLocationLabel" Text="Ticket Location: " />
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketLocationData" Text="{x:Bind TicketLocation}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel01" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Name="StopDateFromLabel" Text="Stop Date From: " />
                            <TextBlock Name="StopDateFromData" Text="{x:Bind StopDateTime}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Name="InvoiceDateLabel" Text="Invoice Date: " />
                            <TextBlock Name="InvoiceDateData" Text="{x:Bind InvoiceDate}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Name="NetBarrelsLabel" Text="Net Barrels: " RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                            <TextBlock Name="NetBarrelsData" Text="{x:Bind NetBarrels}" RelativePanel.RightOf="NetBarrelsLabel" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Name="WaterBarrelsLabel" Text="Water Barrels: " RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                            <TextBlock Name="WaterBarrelsData" Text="{x:Bind NetBarrels}" RelativePanel.RightOf="WaterBarrelsLabel" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel11" Margin="20">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketTypeLabel" Text="Ticket Type: " RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                            <TextBlock Name="TicketTypeData" Text="{x:Bind TicketType}" RelativePanel.RightOf="TicketTypeLabel" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Name="OriginBillingTypeLabel" Text="Origin Billing Type: " RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                            <TextBlock Name="OriginBillingTypeData" Text="{x:Bind OriginBillingType}" RelativePanel.RightOf="OriginBillingTypeLabel" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the `VisualStateManager` work inside a `DataTemplate`, we will need to  place it within a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control) subclass such as a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) like the following:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Ticket}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ticket">
            <UserControl>
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        ...
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

> Visual states are sometimes useful for scenarios where you want to change the state of some area of UI that's not immediately a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control) subclass. You can't do this directly because the *control* parameter of the [GoToState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#Windows_UI_Xaml_VisualStateManager_GoToState_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_System_String_System_Boolean_) method requires a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control) subclass, which refers to the object that the [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager) acts upon.
>
> We recommend you define a custom [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) to either be the  [Window.Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Content) root or be a container for other content you want to apply states to (such as a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel)). Then you can call [GoToState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#Windows_UI_Xaml_VisualStateManager_GoToState_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_System_String_System_Boolean_) on your [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) and apply states regardless of whether the rest of the content is a [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control).

For more info, please see **Visual states for elements that aren't controls** under [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager#remarks) of [VisualStateManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager).

Comment: Thank you very much for the direction. Creating the user control solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @SanjayJain Could you please [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) as it has solved your issue? For more, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) And this will also help others who have the same issue to find the answer more easily. Thanks! ;)

Comment: How can I pass that control into `VisualStateManager.GoToState`?